# fig up fails with error "create_container() takes at least 2 arguments"

Tags: django, docker, fig

I am trying to deploy and run my django application using docker and fig and I am running into the following error.

```
TypeError: create_container() takes at least 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Here's the entire error log and the fig and docker files.  (most of the details such as password are test details as I am just trying to get docker, fig and my sample app running).

Any advice on how to fix this?
Is there a way to further debug (perhaps using pdb) to see the exact arguments to the create_container() call?

```
Error log

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/fig", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fig/cli/main.py", line 31, in main
    command.sys_dispatch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fig/cli/docopt_command.py", line 21, in sys_dispatch
    self.dispatch(sys.argv[1:], None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fig/cli/command.py", line 28, in dispatch
    super(Command, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fig/cli/docopt_command.py", line 24, in dispatch
    self.perform_command(*self.parse(argv, global_options))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fig/cli/command.py", line 56, in perform_command
    handler(project, command_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fig/cli/main.py", line 427, in up
    insecure_registry=insecure_registry,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fig/project.py", line 174, in up
    for (_, container) in service.recreate_containers(insecure_registry=insecure_registry):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fig/service.py", line 199, in recreate_containers
    container = self.create_container(insecure_registry=insecure_registry, **override_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fig/service.py", line 178, in create_container
    return Container.create(self.client, **container_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fig/container.py", line 37, in create
    response = client.create_container(**options)
```

**Fig File**

```
dbdata:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
        - /var/lib/postgres
    command: true

db:
    volumes_from:
        - dbdata
    ports:
        - "5432"

web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0.8000
    volumes:
        - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
        - "8000:8000"
    links:
        - db
    environment:
        - INSTANCE_TYPE=web
        - DEBUG = 1
        - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=django_project.settings
        - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres@db/postgres
```

**Dockerfile**

## Base image and other details

```
FROM python:2.7.8
MAINTAINER xyz
EXPOSE 8000

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
RUN pip install -r /usr/src/requirements.txt

ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE django_project.settings
ENV DATABASE_URL postgres://postgres@db/postgres
 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
CMD [ "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000" ]
```

Comment: Fig doesn't check the yaml, so often a syntax mistake will cause bizarre errors like this. Maybe try taking things out until it works? Also, fig is old now, it would be worth moving to docker compose.

Comment: Oh, and I don't think you can create data containers like that in fig. Instead do it manually outside the yaml file and just link to it in volumes_from.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I am giving docker compose a try. They recommend that the tool not be used for production yet. If I decide to use compose in Dev, what would be the equivalent I use in production?

Comment: Compose started from the same codebase that fig did, I don't think fig was ever recommended for prod use either. I think the assumption now is that most people putting containers in prod are using a container host like DotCloud, Kubernetes, or Tutum to run things in prod.

Comment: Thanks Kevan. will check them out.